# Is there any fast and simple cryption algorithm with public/private keys?

Tags: algorithm, private-key, public-key, crypt

RSA is not suitable for fast cryption. It is also hard to implement.

I want a fast and simple cryption algorithm with public and private keys, instead of using RSA algorithm.

Something like XOR cryption but a public key for encryption and a private key for decryption.

Is there any fast and simple cryption algorithm with public/private keys?

Comment: ElGamal, RSA, Rabin and GM - those are the 4 asymmetric encryption/decryption algorithms that I'm aware of, all of which are pretty much equally complicated. Unless you have a specific coding issue at hand, you would probably be better off posting your question on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You might have more success posting over on: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

ElGamal, RSA, Rabin and GM are the asymmetric encryption/decryption algorithms that I'm aware of.

All of these algorithms are pretty much equally hard to implement.

There are probably better places to post your question, as it doesn't deal with any specific coding issue.

Nevertheless, here is a short summary of the differences between these algorithms:

[image]